# Is n! mod p doable in sub $O(n)$ time?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, factorial

I ask because I can use Lucas Theorem to find ${n \choose k} \mod p$ but don't know of an equivalent for permutations ($n$ permute $k \mod p$).

Comment: For fixed $p$?  $n! \equiv 0 \mod p$ if $n \ge p$.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is actually $n(n-1)(n-2)\dotsm(n-k+1) \pmod{p}$. Is that right?

Comment: well i know how to get combinations quickly and i know the only difference between combinations and permutations is a denominator factor of k!

Comment: But working mod $p$ you should be careful, because this denominator might be zero (mod $p$). The expression I wrote it what you want then. Still, if $k\geq p$ it will be zero.

Comment: Yeah, but you can't divide by $k!$ in general, $\pmod p$, if $k\geq p$.  For example, in general, $\binom {2p}p\equiv 2 \pmod p$. If you instead compute $(2p)!\equiv 0\pmod p$ and $p!\equiv 0\pmod p$ how are you going to compute $$\frac{(2p)!}{p!p!}$$ mod $p$?

Comment: I mean this may be an XY question or whatever. I just want n choose k mod p in fast execution. I just thought the factorial difference was what i needed. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: How big is $n$? How big in $p$? How big in $k$? (approximately)

Comment: arbitrary. i am writing a function

Comment: i also know about the zero condition but i am mainly concerned about nontrivial case k < p

Comment: I that case, I think you should measure your time complexity as a function of $p$. This will help people here understand what you need. I'll think about it.

Comment: technically time complexity of min(n,p) i think, right?

Comment: It also looks like there is an assumption that multiplication is constant.  Are you guaranteed that the numbers are machine words (ie. processor bus/register sized?).  If not, you need to count digits as well, and multiplication is O(n^2) naive or better if fast fourier multiplication and related are used.  Naively, you're actually looking at O(n^2 k) - in other words, your O(n) is wrong as there are O(k) multiplies here, but n is a factor if you aren't looking at machine words.

Comment: Well i can solve it iteratively by multiplying by n-k+1 all the way up modulo p every step. rationale: (n!/((n-k)!)) /(n!/((n-(k-1))!)) = n-k+1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $k\geq p$ then the answer is zero and we're done. Otherwise:

Let $M=\lfloor \sqrt{k}\rfloor$.

1. Define a polynomial: $f(x)=x(x+1)\dotsm (x+M-1)$.
2. There is a divide and conquer algorithm to evaluate $f(x)$ simultaneously at $M$ points (see *Modern Computer Algebra / Joachim von zur Gathen, Jürgen Gerhard*).
3. We will evaluate it at $n-k+1, n-k+1+M,n-k+1+2M,\dotsc,n-k+1+(M-1)M$.
4. We will get the values of $f(n-k+1), f(n-k+1+M),f(n-k+1+2M),\dotsc,f(n-k+1+(M-1)M)$.
5. Now just multiply all of those values to get
   $f(n-k+1)\cdot f(n-k+1+M) \cdot f(n-k+1+2M)\dotsm f(n-k+1+(M-1)M)$.
6. If $\sqrt{k}$ is an integer then we're done. Otherwise, we need up to $M$ more multiplications.

The complexity is about $O(\sqrt{p})$ times some logarithmic factors, so it beats the $O(p)$ naive solution.
(the botteleck with the logarithmic factors is in Step 3).

Comment: All numbers should be taken $\pmod{p}$.

Comment: forgive my ignorance but explain p(x) please?

Comment: You want to multiply $k$ numbers. So I divide them to $\sqrt{k}$ groups of $\sqrt{k}$ numbers. The polynomial $p(x)$ is used to evaluate the proudct of $k$ consecutive integers. That's one such block. Step 4 then calculates the product of each such block and step 5 multiplies the products of the blocks to get to product of all $k$ numbers.

Comment: First, I think there is an error in your definition of $p(x) -$ an extra factor of $x$ seems to have snuck in there. Second, in your comment, I think "$k$ consecutive integers" should be "$M$ consecutive integers". Is that right?

Comment: @TonyK: You are right. Edited the post. I can't edited the comment, but it really should be "$M$ consecutive integers". Thanks.

Comment: You might want to choose some other symbol than $p$ for the polynomial, since it's already used to denote the modulus. Yes, it's evident from context which is meant, but still...

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Agreed. Edited and changed.